# Put TimeZone in two selects tags by just using php, html and vanila js only

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create two dateTimezone Selection because I want to calculate the difference between two dateTimeZone. I have owner class and now I want to put them in two selections with and print them in this format (Y-m-d h:m:s).

Here is PHP code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3pA5.jpg

```
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <select name="selection1" id="selection1">  
        <option name=""></option>
        <option name="Moscow">Moscow</option>
        <option name="Katmandu">Katmandu</option>
        <option name="Damascus">Damascus</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selection2">
        <option name=""></option>
        <option name="Moscow">Moscow</option>
        <option name="Katmandu">Katmandu</option>
        <option name="Damascus">Damascus</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take look at [timezone_offset_get](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php) as well as [List of Supported Timezones](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in PHP's documentation.

Here is an example how to achieve such a result:

```
/**  Returns the offset from the origin timezone to the remote timezone, in seconds.
*    @param $remote_tz;
*    @param $origin_tz; If null the servers current timezone is used as the origin.
*    @return int;
*/
function get_timezone_offset($remote_tz, $origin_tz = null) {
    if($origin_tz === null) {
        if(!is_string($origin_tz = date_default_timezone_get())) {
            return false; // A UTC timestamp was returned -- bail out!
        }
    }
    $origin_dtz = new DateTimeZone($origin_tz);
    $remote_dtz = new DateTimeZone($remote_tz);
    $origin_dt = new DateTime("now", $origin_dtz);
    $remote_dt = new DateTime("now", $remote_dtz);
    $offset = $origin_dtz->getOffset($origin_dt) - $remote_dtz->getOffset($remote_dt);
    return $offset;
}
```

Examples:

```
// This will calculate the difference. It returns 10800 (3 hours) ...
$offset = get_timezone_offset('America/Los_Angeles','America/New_York');
// or, if your server time is already set to 'America/New_York'...
$offset = get_timezone_offset('America/Los_Angeles');
// You can then take $offset and adjust your timestamp.
$offset_time = time() + $offset;

// To display the formatted time
echo date('Y-m-d h:m:s', $offset_time);
```